# Quasar's QTable selected rows are not updated after modification on callback of @selection event

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

There are two events we can use when using QTable's [Selection](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Selection) feature. One is `@update:selected -> function(newSelected)` which fires after a selection (or deselect) is done and reflected. The second is `@selection -> function(details)` which is triggered before the `@update:selected` which happens "on" selecting (or deselect) and before the selected row/s is/are reflected.

Currently I achieved my goal using the `@update:selected` event but I believe it makes more sense if it is done on `@selection`

The idea is when I select rows using the "select all" checkbox (found on the table's header), I need to deselect the rows that aren't supposed to be selectable because of given rules. Individually, I simply disabled each row's checkbox using the prop `disable` with my conditions.

Say for example, each `row` has a property `status` and I don't want to allow to select `rows` with satus `"offline"`. To disable each rows conditionally, we'll have something like this:

```
<template v-slot:body="props">
    <q-tr class="cursor-pointer" :props="props">
        <q-td>
            <q-checkbox v-model="props.selected" :disable="props.row.status === 'offline'"/>
        </q-td>
...
```

Basically, `:disable="props.row.status === 'offline'"` does the job. But using the "select all" checkbox will still select everything. So I tried handling it like this:

template:

```
<q-table
    ...
    @selection="beforeSelection"
    ...
```

method:

```
beforeSelection(selection) {
    selection.rows = selection.rows.filter(r => r.status != 'offline')
    selection.keys = selection.rows.map(r => r.id) // `id` is the `row-key` I had set.
    console.log(selection) // a simple log confirms we modified the seleted rows correctly
}
```

After the modification, I'm expecting that the filtered rows will only be the ones selected. But it seems to not work and the original `details` object given by `@selection` persisted. A simple `@update:selected ="details => console.log(details)"` confirms that the original object persisted. I believe the intention of using the `beforeSelection` on `@selection` was more ideal for a "validation" stage on selecting rows, but this event seems to be useless currently if I am unable to prevent/revert selecting a row conditionally on this event.

Did I miss anything on how to use a `@selection` event?

Comment: Alex how did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You are probably using `:selected.sync` inside `q-table` to bind the data. Replace it by `:selected` should solve your problem.

Comment: This does not solve the problem.